# Editing a file with emacs over ssh on remote machine

Tags: tramp, ssh

I am editing configuration files with emacs on remote hosts using ssh connection. It works perfectly. But I recently made RSA keys and now I can connect to these hosts with the keys without password, but emacs cannot. It is waiting for a long time with message "waiting for prompts from remote shell" and after that says that timeout reached.
I do not understand what is wrong, please clarify :)
Thanks, guys!

---

Thanks for your answers. Will investigate it. 
ZhengHu, I do not think that the deal is about shell settings, because Emacs can connect with these settings when I do not use RSA ssh key...

Comment: Seems your problem is quite common:
https://wikemacs.org/wiki/TRAMP#.22Waiting_for_prompts_from_remote_shell.22_message_error Why is my answer autmatically -1 voted ……

Comment: This needs further analysis, especially Tramp traces. Stackexchange is not suited for this kind of analysis, so I recommend you to write a Tramp bug report.